# Get uploaded image from form as byte array

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

I have a JSP/Servlet application that has a form containing multiple parts.

Client side:

```
        out.println("<form action='cbehindRegister_submit.php' method='post'enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">");
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tbody>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><label>Username: </label></td>");
        out.println("<td><input type='text' required id='input_username' name='input_username'/></td>");
        out.println("<td><label id='valusername' class='val'> </label></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><label>Country: </label></td>");
        out.println("<td><input type='text' required id='input_country' name='input_country'/></td>");
        out.println("<td><label id='valcountry' class='val'> </label></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><label>Profile picture: </label></td>");
        out.println("<td><input type='file' required id='input_profile_picture' name='input_profile_picture' accept='image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg' /></td>");
        out.println("<td><label id='valprofile_picture' class='val'> </label></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><label>Birth date: </label></td>");
        out.println("<td><input type='date' required id='input_birth_date' name='input_birth_date' /></td>");
        out.println("<td><label id='valbrith_date' class='val'> </label></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><label>Password: </label></td>");
        out.println("<td><input type='password' required id='input_password' name='input_password' /></td>");
        out.println("<td><label id='valpassword' class='val'> </label></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td><label>Verify password: </label></td>");
        out.println("<td><input type='password' required id='input_verifypassword' name='input_verifypassword' /></td>");
        out.println("<td><label id='valverifypassword' class='val' > </label></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        //request
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td height='45px' colspan='3'><input type='submit' id='submit' value='Registreer' id='regsubmit' /></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("</tbody>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</form>");
```

The question is how can I get the file uploaded as an byte array so that it can be stored as blob in a database?

Is there anyway of getting the file on a similar way
 as

```
File file =  request.getParameter("nameOfFormParameter");
```

or

```
byte[] image =  request.getParameter("nameOfFormParameter");
```

Most guides on the internet are for storing the file as is on the server.

EDIT 1: Most questions relating file upload give a solution that stores the files on disk and dont handle the files in memory. The purpose of this question is to find a solution that handles uploaded file in memory without writing the files directly to disk , but stores them in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for around 2 days I finally found the answer:

**Firstly**

add enctype=\"multipart/form-data\  in the form tag so that the result is :

```
<form action='cbehindRegister_submit.php' method='post'enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
```

**Secondly**

use the following line of code to receive the file (be sure that the **name of the input tag** of the form is the same as the string in the getPart function):

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("input_profile_picture");
```

**Thirdly**

create an inputstream from the filePart and convert the inputstream to a byte array

```
InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();
byte[] fileAsByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(filecontent);
```

Now , the image is ready to be blobbed!